# How to use the "No Reply" Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Address in Email Alerts?

Tags: email, email-alert, release-update

We are using our noreply@example.com to send emails from some of our Email Alerts. However, the "Use a Default No-Reply Address as System Address for Case Email Notifications" release update requires (eventually) us to setup a no reply email address as a Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Address.

As we are testing this update, it became clear that in order to use the same no reply email address in the Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Address section, we have to remove it from the User Selectable Organization-Wide Email Address. The problem is this email address is tied to multiple email alerts.

So as a test, we setup a temporary address in the Special Purpose section to see if we could even use that address as the From address in Email Alerts, and we cannot.

Does anyone know of a way to continue to use a single no reply email address in Email Alerts as well as have it setup as a Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Address?

Something noteworthy to mention, under the release update "How is my org impacted", it reads:

> To enable this update, first configure a default No-Reply address. Otherwise, when you turn on Send Case Notifications from System Address, email notifications for incoming emails on existing cases, Case Comment, Case Escalation, and Case Assignment are sent from noreply@salesforce.com. The notifications lack important information, and eventually stop sending.

This statement is utterly confusing, to me at least. But I think what it's saying is if we don't setup and configure our own no reply email address for case notifications, Salesforce will stop sending emails from noreply@salesforce.com some time in the future.

Comment: your interpretation is the same as mine; we had a user-selectable noreply@mycompany.com ORGwide email address and for the default no-reply email address we're using no-reply@mycompany.com _Note the hyphen_

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion @cropredy.